# How to apply the linux 'file' command to the output (STDOUT) of a program to determine its file type

Tags: linux, file, stdin, file-descriptor, io-redirection

I want to determine the file-type of the contents of the STDOUT output of a program (without first saving the output to a file)
i.e., notionally, I would like to run: `myprogram | file`

However, `/usr/bin/file can't read from STDIN.

If I try something like: `my program | file <(cat /dev/stdin)`, I get the error `broken symbolic link to pipe:[460261257]`

I know I could save the output to a temp file, run `file` on the temp file and then erase the temp file but that seems very kludgy.

So is there any bash magic with redirection and/or file descriptors that will allow me to determine the file-type of the output of a program?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-` file name to specify to `file` you want to read from stdin

ex. `cat myfile | file -`

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks! I forgot about '-' :)

Answer (score 0):

Use command substitution:

```
file <(myprogram)
```

This might not work if `file` needs to seek in the file, since the argument will be a named pipe.